# How put a variable in a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this link and this variable:

```
var fin = "SAT000000002574";
"http://sat3.altervista.org/index.php?id='+fin'"
```

I don't know how i have to write this link. I have syntax problem.
I tried but the link is ever wrong. Help me

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply using a `+` to concatenate the `fin` variable here:

```
var fin = "SAT000000002574";
"http://sat3.altervista.org/index.php?id="+fin
```

Answer (score 0):

youre mixing double quotes with single quotes

```
 "http://sat3.altervista.org/index.php?id="+fin
```

Answer (score 0):

Interpolation is not standard in javascript. Maybe this can help you http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf

Contatination is your best option, but the methods below can also help.

```
String.concat();

["foo", "bar"].join("");
```