# Put a variable inside a link in jquery function

Tags: jquery, html

i have this html page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Parsing</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <script>
        $.getJSON(
                var fin = "SAT000000002574";
                "http://sat3.altervista.org/index.php?id="+fin , { get_param: 'value' }, 
                function(data) {
                for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                    var lin = data[i]["Nr SAT"];
                    $('body').append($('<p>').html('Numero Sat: <a href ="http://sat3.altervista.org/NuovoFile.html?id=' + lin + '">'+ data[i]["Nr SAT"] + '</a>'));        
                    $('body').append($('<p>').html('Data Apertura: '+ data[i]["Data Apertura"]));
                }
        });
        </script>
    <body>
        <header>
            <img id="logo" src="img/img2.png" alt="logo_chiave_inglese" />
        </header> 
    </body>
</html>
```

In the part of code written below i tried to put the value of the variable fin in the link of the php page. This code it doesn't work because the link is incorrect. Someone can tell me how i have to write the link for put inside him the variable?

```
$.getJSON(
var fin = "SAT000000002574";
"http://sat3.altervista.org/index.php?id="+fin , { get_param: 'value' },
```

Comment: Hmm, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23611490/how-put-a-variable-in-a-link

Answer (score 0):

```
var fin = "SAT000000002574";
$.getJSON( "http://sat3.altervista.org/index.php?id=" + fin, {
    get_param: 'value'
}, function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var lin = data[i]["Nr SAT"];
        $('body').append($('<p>').html('Numero Sat: <a href ="http://sat3.altervista.org/NuovoFile.html?id=' + lin + '">' + data[i]["Nr SAT"] + '</a>'));
        $('body').append($('<p>').html('Data Apertura: ' + data[i]["Data Apertura"]));
    }
});
```

Comment: This code works...now in which way i can take the value of the variable id in the page php??

Comment: @user3628914 `$_GET['id'];` is a way

Answer (score 0):

You have put a statement in the middle of the parameters for the `getJSON` call. Just put the variable declaration before the call:

```
var fin = "SAT000000002574";
$.getJSON(
  "http://sat3.altervista.org/index.php?id=" + fin,
  { get_param: 'value' }, 
  function(data) {
    ...
```